# How would I write the Granger Causality formula in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols

I require to write the Granger Causality formula in Latex for a project that I am undertaking. I do not, however, know how to produce the formula in math mode. Please can someone either point me towards a database of symbols and their corresponding Latex symbols or provide the Latex code for the formula itself. The formula, taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality is as follows:

[image: Granger Causality Formula]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It looks like `\[ \mathbb{P}[Y(t+1) \in A \vert \mathcal{I}(t)] \neq \mathbb{P}[Y(t+1) \in \vert \mathcal{I}_{-X}(t)] \]` to me (you should probably load `amsmath` and `amssymb` for that). I would recommend to pack some parts of this up in useful macros. I for example always have `\newcommand*{\prob}{\mathbb{P}}`, so I can type `\prob(A)`.

Comment: @moewe that's great! loading amssymb worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I just realised: Since the picture is from Wikipedia you can get the MathJax code from looking at the source there, that should be close enough to the LaTeX code.

Comment: If you inspect the element in the Wikipedia page, you find `{\displaystyle \mathbb {P} [Y(t+1)\in A\mid {\mathcal {I}}(t)]\neq \mathbb {P} [Y(t+1)\in A\mid {\mathcal {I}}_{-X}(t)],}`. A more proper LaTeX markup would be `\mathbb {P} [Y(t+1)\in A\mid \mathcal {I}(t)]\neq \mathbb {P} [Y(t+1)\in A\mid \mathcal {I}_{-X}(t)]` (add the comma depending on the context).

Comment: @moewe Actually [Wikipedia uses LaTeX not MathJax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367725/does-wikipedia-use-latex/367730#367730) currently, though it's still not always great to copy.